# Regex - How to match an entire string and capture only a subgroup if it it is certain length

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I would like some help with this regex in Javascript I'm working with where users type a ticket number into chat.

I am working with the following possibilities and the regex `TTN-\d{1,4}?([0-9]{1,9})`.

The number of digits possible is 10 but sometimes users will not include the leading zeroes so I need to be sure to match strings with up to 10 digits; however, the issue I am having is that it will still capture if there are greater than 10 digits.

I want to match against the follow here and capture the digits after "TTN-"

`random word TTN-484424 random word` - I would capture 4844254. Works good.

`TTN-0000846110` - I would capture 0000846110. Works good.

`hey look at TTN-0000844555 blah blah` - I would capture 0000844555. Works good.

`random word TTN-00099999990980 random word` - I would not want to match this string because the number of digits is greater than 10; therefore, the user incorrectly typed the ticket number.

I've been reading up on regex tutorials and tried using `$' to signify the end of the string but that doesn't work since it still goes on in length.

How can I signify the regex to only start matching when the digits of the string are <= 10?

Thank you!

Comment: Any code which you tried so far?

Comment: It is above within the inline code: TTN-\d{1,4}?([0-9]{1,9})

Comment: What is the intent behind `\d{1,4}?`?

Comment: The intent behind `\d{1,4}?` is that the preceding leading zeroes of 4 is optional.

Comment: I did \d to allow for numbers of 6 in length. So `random word TTN-484424 random word` would match and capture the digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries.

```
TTN-(\d{1,10})\b
```

`\d{1,10}` matches 1 to 10 digit chars.
`\b` word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

Comment: Why use a word boundary?

Comment: This works and makes sense now. I will further look into word boundaries. @sln do you not think he should use word boundaries?

Comment: There is no word boundary between 8a.

Comment: There is no `8a` in question

Comment: `How can I signify the regex to only start matching when the digits of the string are <= 10?` There is no `word boundary` in question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't allow a digit after up to 10.

`TTN-(\d{1,10})(?!\d)`

Comment: This works but the word boundary answer is more specific. If a user entered `TTN-0000844555blah` it would match and it wouldn't be allowed in our case.

Comment: You'll have to further explain.

Comment: ITs wrong because a word boundary could match `TTN-0000844555=blah` . You just can't make things up to suite your needs. The only thing you know is it can't be a digit  in the next position. Otherwise, you have to force what form you need. Word boundaries are too general !! If it got to be a <space> use a space, etc..

Comment: Oh I see...but your solution `TTN-(\d{1,10})(?!\d)` also matches `TTN-0000844555=blah` which is incorrect. Take a look here https://regex101.com/r/zP3rW5/6

Comment: Its only incorrect because you say so. But you haven't stated a correct path.

Comment: It was my misunderstanding that characters such as `=` were not considered inside word boundaries. If I were aware I would have been more explicit in my question.

Comment: Word boundaries, like all assertions exist _between_ characters. `\b` is a fairly complex expression if you care to look it up. Using word boundary in your case is not the best way to go. Its better to know your format and code to it's form. Otherwise, the only thing you know is the next character is _not a digit_.